# How to add the same relation multiple times in the OctoberCMS backend?

Tags: octobercms, octobercms-backend

For example, lets take two models: `Invoice` and `Product`
I'm using the default `belongsToMany` relationship.

But I need to add a product to the invoice multiple times (with different pivot data). It seems that the backend uses related model ID-s for managing the relations and therefore it is not possible to add the same model multiple times.

So, what can be done to add the same product multiple times to the invoice?

Comment: How did you solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Use repeater type of field.

Here have example: https://octobercms.com/forum/post/form-widgets-repeater?page=1

Notice that you need to add `protected $jsonable = ['your_field'];` in your model file.

Comment: This would work in some cases but I need to keep the original database structure so the data is stored in a separate table